# Drawn polygons with different colours for negative and positive areas

Tags: r

I want to colour the following time series graphic with 2 different colour tones depending on the value.

[image]

I have used the following code:

```
plot(differences$date,  differences$differences,  type = "n", las = 1, ylab = "", xlab = "",
     ylim = c(-700,700), xaxt = "n", yaxt="n")

polygon(cbind(c(min(differences$date), differences$date, max(differences$date)), 
              c(0,differences$differences,
                0)), col= gc, border = T)
```

I tried using this code to assign colours depending on positive or negative values, but it doesn't work.

```
g <- cumsum(is.na(as.numeric(differences$differences)))
gc <- ifelse(tapply(y, g, 
    function(x) x[which.max(abs(x))])>0, 
    "red","green")
```

Any ideas on how to do it?